# Spark Merge two dataframes and create a single dataframe by overriding the value from the 2nd dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

How can I merge two dataframes in Apache Spark and create a single dataframe by overriding the value from the 2nd dataframe?

Input:

```
val r1 = Seq((1, "A1_1"), (2, "A2_1"), (3, "A3_1"), (4, "A4_1")).toDF("c1","c2")
val r2 = Seq((3, "A3_2"), (4, "A4_2"), (5, "A5_2"), (6, "A6_2")).toDF("c1","c2")
```

Desired output

```
+---+----+
| c1|  c2|
+---+----+
|  1|A1_1|
|  2|A2_1|
|  3|A3_2|
|  4|A4_2|
|  5|A5_2|
|  6|A6_2|
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outer `join` (alias for dataframes are needed as both contains same column names) and `coalesce` inbuilt function (`coalesce` will return first not null column inside it) should get your desired output

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
r1.as("r1").join(r2.as("r2"), col("r1.c1") === col("r2.c1"), "outer")
  .select(coalesce(col("r1.c1"), col("r2.c1")).as("c1"), coalesce(col("r2.c2"), col("r1.c2")).as("c2"))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+----+
|c1 |c2  |
+---+----+
|1  |A1_1|
|6  |A6_2|
|3  |A3_2|
|5  |A5_2|
|4  |A4_2|
|2  |A2_1|
+---+----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful